# Novel about a group of people hunting/fighting demons in dreams

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the title and author of a novel I read in the 80s or 90s. It was about a group of people who had the ability (and therefore the mission) to find/hunt/fight demons in people's dreams when they were asleep. I do not remember whether they wandered into other people's dreams or whether they were their own, but if it was someone else's dream, they had to leave the dream before the person woke up.

Quite at the beginning there was a scene in which a corpse was found on the beach, from the inside of which demons were "born" into the normal world.
"Born" meaning the belly was open and the demons had left the body as some sort of eels.

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like [*Night Warriors*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11124) (1986) by Graham Masterton.

Three random people, Henry, Susan, and Gil find a corpse whose stomach has been eaten out by eels and they are then forced to hunt and fight the demon that is impregnating women while they sleep.

Quoting the description on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2238121.Night_Warriors):

> Henry was the first to reach the body, while Gil and Susan walked cautiously closer, and then stood watching. It was the body of a beautiful young girl, naked, like a peacefully sleeping mermaid. Never in their most traumatic nightmares could they have imagined the convulsive violence which followed...
>
> Then each is visited by a mysteriously androgynous figure who reveals that the girl had been used as innocent host to the most hideous malevolence known to man, a horrific presence that, through grotesque acts of impregnation, is madly insinuating itself into the bodies and minds of thousands of unsuspecting people.
>
> The only hope is to destroy the original seed, and together Henry, Gil and Susan become *Night Warriors*, an ancient Order of men and women charged with the power to enter and search for the abomination in a fantastic dream world of soaring exhilaration and searing terror, driven by the inescapable reality that if they fail to find the beast, then the beast will certainly find them...

When the police and medical examiner turn over the girl's body:

> The girl's abdomen had been completely ripped out from her ribs to her pelvis, and inside her abdominal cavity scores of silvery-black eels were writhing, a tumultuous nest of slithering creatures twining and untwining themselves, blindly feeding on what was left of the girl's softer organs.